# Representation List in python

Tags: python

i want to change the representation of my list..
after this code i writh the output, i tried without success 
so if anyone can help me I'd appreciate it

```
empty_rlist = None

def make_rlist(first,rest):
    return (first, rest)

def first(s):
    return s[0]

def rest(s):
    return s[1]

def len_rlist(s):

    length = 0
    while s != empty_rlist:
        s, length = rest(s), length + 1
    return length

def getitem_rlist(s, i):
    while i > 0:
        s, i = rest(s), i - 1
    return first(s)

def make_mutable_rlist():

    contents = empty_rlist

    def length():
        return len_rlist(contents)

    def get_item(ind):
        return getitem_rlist(contents, ind)

    def push_first(value):
        nonlocal contents
        contents = make_rlist(value, contents)

    def pop_first():
        nonlocal contents
        f = first(contents)
        contents = rest(contents)
        return f

    def str():
        return str(contents)

    return {'length':length, 'get_item':get_item, 'push_first':push_first,'pop_first': pop_first, 'str':str }    


my_list = make_mutable_rlist()
for x in range(4):
    my_list['push_first'](x)

print(my_list['str']())
```

I need to change the str function realization:
This gives me the result

```
(1, (2, (3, (4, None))))
```

but what I want is

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Then change your `str` "method" to generate that.

Comment: I edit my post  .. and i dont know how to do this

Comment: "I tried without success": what did you try, and in what way(s) was it unsuccessful?

Comment: def str():
            tmp = []
            for i in range (length()):
                tmp.append(get_item(i)) 
            return tmp

Comment: "...and in what way(s) was it unsuccessful?"

Comment: I should use this list later, for example write a function that takes in a number into specific index, Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why are you avoiding the use of a proper `class` for this? Using nested functions like this (particularly having them referenced via a `dict`) is just pathologically ugly.

Comment: Yes i know ,  but this how i need to do this

Comment: You really should read more about OOP. What you need is to override the `__str__` method of the `list` class. For that, you need to subclass it.